# UV issues when creating polygon geometry in maya with python

Tags: python, maya

I am working on a plugin for Maya 2013 written in python for importing polygon geometry (think importer for custom OBJ like format).  I am running into an issue where I can't get the UVs to appear in the UV Editor even though I generate them with the code. I checked for the number of UVs and know they have been created but can't seem to see where to find them. I know this can be tricky (something to do with having to create a dummy UV set) but I am looking for insight into what causes this issue and how to get around it. Any ideas?

---

**Sample Code:**

```
UVSetNames = ['map1', 'other']

meshFS = maya.OpenMaya.MFnMesh()

newMesh = meshFS.create(numVertices, numFaces, points, faceCounts, faceConnects, uArray, vArray, outputMesh)    # ADDING THE UVs TO THE MESH AT THE SAME TIME
meshFS.updateSurface()
nodeName = meshFS.name()

print 'Mesh node name is: %s' % nodeName

# CREATE THE UV SET
meshFS.createUVSetWithName( UVSetNames[1] )
meshFS.setUVs(uArray, vArray, UVSetNames[1] )

maya.cmds.sets(nodeName, e=True, fe='initialShadingGroup')

print "A) NUM UVs (%s): %d" % (UVSetNames[0], meshFS.numUVs( UVSetNames[0] ) )
print "B) NUM UVs (%s): %d" % (UVSetNames[1], meshFS.numUVs( UVSetNames[1] ) )
```

---

**RESULTS:**

```
VERT COUNT: 23088

FACE COUNT: 36019

CREATING VERTICIES

Mesh node name is: polySurfaceShape1

A) NUM UVs (map1): 23088

B) NUM UVs (other): 23088
```

---

### Scene File Sample

```
//Maya ASCII 2013 scene
//Name: example.ma
//Last modified: Mon, Oct 28, 2013 08:49:03 PM
//Codeset: UTF-8
requires maya "2013";
currentUnit -l centimeter -a degree -t film;
fileInfo "application" "maya";
fileInfo "product" "Maya 2013";
fileInfo "version" "2013 x64";
fileInfo "cutIdentifier" "201202220220-825135";
fileInfo "osv" "Mac OS X 10.8.5";
createNode transform -n "polySurface360";
createNode mesh -n "polySurfaceShape360" -p "polySurface360";
    setAttr -k off ".v";
    setAttr ".vir" yes;
    setAttr ".vif" yes;
    setAttr ".uvst[0].uvsn" -type "string" "map1";
    setAttr ".cuvs" -type "string" "map1";
    setAttr ".dcc" -type "string" "Ambient+Diffuse";
    setAttr ".covm[0]"  0 1 1;
    setAttr ".cdvm[0]"  0 1 1;
    setAttr -s 52 ".vt[0:51]"  -0.48699999 0.3705 0.1415 -0.52670002 0.3292 0.1186
         -0.52670002 0.35049999 -0.1302 -0.48699999 0.3964 -0.13240001 0.15009999 0.3705 0.1415
         0.15009999 0.3964 -0.13240001 0.18979999 0.35049999 -0.1302 0.18979999 0.3292 0.1186
         -0.43880001 0.40380001 0.1603 -0.43880001 0.43329999 -0.1302 0.1019 0.40380001 0.1603
         0.1019 0.43329999 -0.1302 -0.48030001 0.40740001 -0.25080001 -0.4303 0.4443 -0.2446
         -0.43450001 0.44060001 -0.2 -0.48370001 0.4034 -0.2022 0.1435 0.40740001 -0.25080001
         0.1468 0.4034 -0.2022 0.0977 0.44060001 -0.2 0.093400002 0.4443 -0.2446 -0.52170002 0.36129999 -0.25850001
         -0.52410001 0.3572 -0.2 0.1848 0.36129999 -0.25850001 0.18719999 0.3572 -0.2 -0.3802 0.4303 0.1762
         -0.3802 0.4632 -0.1302 0.043400001 0.4303 0.1762 0.043400001 0.4632 -0.1302 -0.32170001 0.45120001 0.1895
         -0.32170001 0.48719999 -0.1302 -0.0151 0.45120001 0.1895 -0.0151 0.48719999 -0.1302
         -0.36950001 0.4743 -0.2404 -0.3087 0.4984 -0.23630001 -0.31529999 0.49489999 -0.2
         -0.37490001 0.4707 -0.2 0.032600001 0.4743 -0.2404 0.037999999 0.4707 -0.2 -0.021600001 0.49489999 -0.2
         -0.028200001 0.4984 -0.23630001 -0.1684 0.46470001 0.19859999 -0.24510001 0.4603 0.1956
         -0.24510001 0.49759999 -0.1302 -0.1684 0.50279999 -0.1302 -0.091799997 0.49759999 -0.1302
         -0.091799997 0.4603 0.1956 -0.2419 0.50529999 -0.2 -0.2386 0.50870001 -0.2351 -0.094999999 0.50529999 -0.2
         -0.098300003 0.50870001 -0.2351 -0.1684 0.51050001 -0.2 -0.1684 0.51389998 -0.2339;
    setAttr -s 123 ".ed[0:122]"  0 1 0 1 2 0 2 0 1 2 3 1 3 0 1 4 5 1 5 6 1
         6 4 1 6 7 0 7 4 0 8 0 0 3 8 1 3 9 1 9 8 1 10 11 1 11 5 1 5 10 1 4 10 0 12 13 0 13 14 1
         14 12 1 14 15 1 15 12 1 16 17 1 17 18 1 18 16 1 18 19 1 19 16 0 20 12 0 15 20 1 15 21 1
         21 20 0 22 23 0 23 17 1 17 22 1 16 22 0 14 9 1 9 15 1 3 15 1 17 5 1 11 17 1 11 18 1
         3 21 1 2 21 0 23 6 0 5 23 1 24 8 0 9 24 1 9 25 1 25 24 1 26 27 1 27 11 1 11 26 1
         10 26 0 28 24 0 25 28 1 25 29 1 29 28 1 30 31 1 31 27 1 27 30 1 26 30 0 32 33 0 33 34 1
         34 32 1 34 35 1 35 32 1 36 37 1 37 38 1 38 36 1 38 39 1 39 36 0 13 32 0 35 13 1 35 14 1
         18 37 1 37 19 1 36 19 0 34 29 1 29 35 1 25 35 1 37 27 1 31 37 1 31 38 1 25 14 1 27 18 1
         40 41 0 41 42 1 42 40 1 42 43 1 43 40 1 43 44 1 44 40 1 44 45 1 45 40 0 29 42 1 41 29 1
         41 28 0 30 45 0 45 31 1 44 31 1 46 34 1 33 46 1 33 47 0 47 46 1 48 49 1 49 39 0 39 48 1
         38 48 1 50 46 1 47 50 1 47 51 0 51 50 1 51 49 0 49 50 1 48 50 1 34 42 1 46 42 1 44 48 1
         38 44 1 50 43 1 43 46 1 43 48 1;
    setAttr -s 72 -ch 216 ".fc[0:71]" -type "polyFaces" 
        f 3 0 1 2
        f 3 -3 3 4
        f 3 5 6 7
        f 3 -8 8 9
        f 3 10 -5 11
        f 3 -12 12 13
        f 3 14 15 16
        f 3 -17 -6 17
        f 3 18 19 20
        f 3 -21 21 22
        f 3 23 24 25
        f 3 -26 26 27
        f 3 28 -23 29
        f 3 -30 30 31
        f 3 32 33 34
        f 3 -35 -24 35
        f 3 -22 36 37
        f 3 -38 -13 38
        f 3 39 -16 40
        f 3 -41 41 -25
        f 3 -31 -39 42
        f 3 -43 -4 43
        f 3 44 -7 45
        f 3 -46 -40 -34
        f 3 46 -14 47
        f 3 -48 48 49
        f 3 50 51 52
        f 3 -53 -15 53
        f 3 54 -50 55
        f 3 -56 56 57
        f 3 58 59 60
        f 3 -61 -51 61
        f 3 62 63 64
        f 3 -65 65 66
        f 3 67 68 69
        f 3 -70 70 71
        f 3 72 -67 73
        f 3 -74 74 -20
        f 3 -27 75 76
        f 3 -77 -68 77
        f 3 -66 78 79
        f 3 -80 -57 80
        f 3 81 -60 82
        f 3 -83 83 -69
        f 3 -75 -81 84
        f 3 -85 -49 -37
        f 3 -42 -52 85
        f 3 -86 -82 -76
        f 3 86 87 88
        f 3 -89 89 90
        f 3 -91 91 92
        f 3 -93 93 94
        f 3 95 -88 96
        f 3 -97 97 -58
        f 3 -59 98 99
        f 3 -100 -94 100
        f 3 101 -64 102
        f 3 -103 103 104
        f 3 105 106 107
        f 3 -108 -71 108
        f 3 109 -105 110
        f 3 -111 111 112
        f 3 -113 113 114
        f 3 -115 -106 115
        f 3 -96 -79 116
        f 3 -117 -102 117
        f 3 118 -109 119
        f 3 -120 -84 -101
        f 3 -110 120 121
        f 3 -122 -90 -118
        f 3 -119 -92 122
        f 3 -123 -121 -116;
    setAttr ".cd" -type "dataPolyComponent" Index_Data Edge 0 ;
    setAttr ".cvd" -type "dataPolyComponent" Index_Data Vertex 0 ;
    setAttr ".hfd" -type "dataPolyComponent" Index_Data Face 0 ;
createNode lightLinker -s -n "lightLinker1";
    setAttr -s 2 ".lnk";
    setAttr -s 2 ".slnk";
createNode displayLayerManager -n "layerManager";
createNode displayLayer -n "defaultLayer";
createNode renderLayerManager -n "renderLayerManager";
createNode renderLayer -n "defaultRenderLayer";
    setAttr ".g" yes;
select -ne :time1;
    setAttr ".o" 1;
    setAttr ".unw" 1;
select -ne :renderPartition;
    setAttr -s 2 ".st";
select -ne :initialShadingGroup;
    setAttr ".ro" yes;
select -ne :initialParticleSE;
    setAttr ".ro" yes;
select -ne :defaultShaderList1;
    setAttr -s 2 ".s";
select -ne :postProcessList1;
    setAttr -s 2 ".p";
select -ne :defaultRenderingList1;
select -ne :renderGlobalsList1;
select -ne :hardwareRenderGlobals;
    setAttr ".ctrs" 256;
    setAttr ".btrs" 512;
select -ne :defaultHardwareRenderGlobals;
    setAttr ".fn" -type "string" "im";
    setAttr ".res" -type "string" "ntsc_4d 646 485 1.333";
relationship "link" ":lightLinker1" ":initialShadingGroup.message" ":defaultLightSet.message";
relationship "link" ":lightLinker1" ":initialParticleSE.message" ":defaultLightSet.message";
relationship "shadowLink" ":lightLinker1" ":initialShadingGroup.message" ":defaultLightSet.message";
relationship "shadowLink" ":lightLinker1" ":initialParticleSE.message" ":defaultLightSet.message";
connectAttr "layerManager.dli[0]" "defaultLayer.id";
connectAttr "renderLayerManager.rlmi[0]" "defaultRenderLayer.rlid";
connectAttr "defaultRenderLayer.msg" ":defaultRenderingList1.r" -na;
// End of example.ma
```

Comment: I dont think your code snippet is enough info.

Comment: did you call updateSurface again after adding UV's?

Comment: could you save the above (or something similar) in Maya ASCII, and if small share it in the question above or else in [pastebin](http://www.pastebin.com) and share the link.

Comment: I've got everything up that should help give clues.

Answer (score 3):

From your sample code I see that you haven't assigned the UVs to the geometry. The create() and setUVs() method will create a texture table with the uv arrays you have provided but would not assign it to the mesh. You need to call assignUVs() after you have called create() or setUVs() to finish up the process as suggested in the API doc: [create()](http://docs.autodesk.com/MAYAUL/2013/ENU/Maya-API-Documentation/cpp_ref/class_m_fn_mesh.html#a52ee98712c8f4460342b2fc5d91dba3b), [setUVs()](http://docs.autodesk.com/MAYAUL/2013/ENU/Maya-API-Documentation/cpp_ref/class_m_fn_mesh.html#a51bf5200523771e59ec4bf4c6bfdd0bc) and [assignUVs()](http://docs.autodesk.com/MAYAUL/2013/ENU/Maya-API-Documentation/cpp_ref/class_m_fn_mesh.html#aecf710967d185b161c044dd95c04345b). You can verify this by calling [getAssignedUVs()](http://docs.autodesk.com/MAYAUL/2013/ENU/Maya-API-Documentation/cpp_ref/class_m_fn_mesh.html#abe6b4afaec85f867401eb3658c3e5459). Hope this helped!